# How do I find why I can't reproduce a database update race that I observe in my production database?

Tags: sql, concurrency, transactions, azure-sql-database, race-condition

I have a SQL Azure database that runs code more or less equivalent to this:

```
declare @magic int;
begin tran 
   select @magic=Magic from MagicTable where MagicId=SomeMagicValue;
   update MagicTable set Magic=Magic+SomeValue where MagicId=SomeMagicValue;
commit tran
```

and I know for sure that sometimes if this code runs in two concurrent transactions with the same value of `SomrMagicValue` there happens a race and the value in column `Magic` for that `MagicId` gets not incremented enough - clearly the two transactions start and read the same value and then increment that same value and so one of them overwrites the result of the other one.

So I decided I needed to add some locking hints. To validate my changes I wanted to reproduce the issue on a test database first. So I created a table with the same schema, added some data there and run the following code:

```
declare @counter int;
set @counter=0;
begin tran
   while @counter < 10000
   begin
       declare @magic int;
       select @magic=Magic from MagicTable where MagicId=SomeMagicValue;
       update MagicTable set Magic=Magic+SomeValue where MagicId=SomeMagicValue;
       set @counter = @counter + 1;
   end
commit tran
```

and this code is run in two concurrent transactions from inside Azure Management portal and each run takes several dozen seconds and there's never a race - my problem is not reproduced.

I also tried the following variant:

```
declare @counter int;
set @counter=0;
while @counter < 10000
begin
    begin tran
       declare @magic int;
       select @magic=Magic from MagicTable where MagicId=SomeMagicValue;
       update MagicTable set Magic=Magic+SomeValue where MagicId=SomeMagicValue;
    commit tran
    set @counter = @counter + 1;
end
```

and again there's never a race - the results are the same as if the transactions would not be concurrent.

The question is - how do I find why the problem is there in the production environment and not in the testing one?

Comment: 1. How do you know it doesn't happen? How do you validate the test correctness? 2. Run with more than 2 concurrent (10, 20). The probability of happening depends on many factors. Your production box may experience high CPU *from other tenants* which would increase probability of thread suspend (yield) between `SELECT` and `UPDATE`.

Comment: @RemusRusanu: First, there's no *box* - both databases are in SQL Azure so I have no freaking idea of how they are influenced by other tenants. I know it doesn't happen because after the two transactions complete I `SELECT` the column value and see it's got larger by exactly 20000.

Comment: The Azure DB box which host your production tenancy.

Comment: @RemusRusanu: Well, SQL Azure is a complex this running on multiple boxes simultaneously and each can host more than one "database server", so it's nearly impossible to say who shares what with whom.

Answer (score 0):

```
begin tran 
   update MagicTable set Magic=Magic+SomeValue where MagicId=SomeMagicValue;
commit tran
```

Your select in the first query is redundant; you never use @Magic and you don't actually need it. If you do as above, the transaction should take care of race conditions. Who knows? It may not be a race but a bug in your code calling the DB somewhere...

Comment: The `SELECT` is not redundant in the real code, that's why I showed it.